# Unexpected token square bracket in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a simple example:

```
for (i = 1; i < totalRows; i++) {
    if(rows[i][10] == null)  {
    spreadsheet.add({ [i]: { 10: "Added" } });
    }
}
```

why do I get an error "Unexpected token [" here:

```
spreadsheet.add({ [i] : { 10:
                  ^
```

I am trying to run the app on `nodejs` version `v0.10.35`,
I cant update it as its a free server provided by **OpenShift**.
It runs fine on my `localhost` computer with `nodejs v4.4.7`

Please advice a workaround for this code, so it could be executed.

Basically what this code does is, it looks in every row if `column 10 is empty`, and if its empty, it adds **Added**

Comment: it should be `i: {}`

Comment: why do you want to use square bracket

Comment: That's a **computed property** and is supported on v4, but not v0.10. See http://node.green/#object-literal-extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defining an object property invalidly.

This is the code that will work:

```
for (i = 1; i < totalRows; i++) {
    if(rows[i][10] == null)  {
      var obj = {};
      obj[i] = { 10: "Added" };
      spreadsheet.add(obj);
    }
}
```

Check MDN documentation regarding the working with properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects